# tslint prefer-const warning when using dot notation

Tags: typescript, tslint

```
interface obj {
  bar: string
}

function randomFunction() {
  let foo: obj = { bar: "" }
  foo.bar = "hip"
}

let snack: obj = { bar: "" }
snack.bar = "hop"
```

I get this warning from tslint:

> Identifier 'foo' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'let'.
>   (prefer-const)

Funny though I don't get this warning in the second case with the variable `snack`.

I can get rid of this warning (which clutters my console when transcompiling) with
`/* tslint:disable: prefer-const */`

I haven't found any bug report on the [tslint project](https://github.com/palantir/tslint).
Since I'm new to typescript I'm wondering: Do I something wrong here?

Comment: It is related to eslint. For a better understanding of this, head over to https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-const. I hope it helps.

Comment: I get a warning with `snack`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tslint is asking you to change `let` to `const` because the identifier `foo` is not reassigned.

The error can be removed by instead writing `const`:

```
const foo: obj = { bar: "" };
foo.bar = "hip";
```

Note that the `const` modifier just means you can't reassign the identifier:

```
 const foo = { bar: "" };
 foo = { bar: "" }; // error
```

It doesn't make the object itself readonly.